# How to change the background color to only 1 combo item chosen select from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, combobox, jquery-selectors

I need to create a function from javascritp that changes the color of the item ie ".chosen-container .chosen-results li.active-result"

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We cannot help you with code we cannot see, nor is it clear what the image is meant to show us.

Comment: The question is clear, I want to change the background color of each combo item

Comment: *"The question is clear"* ***sigh*** Which is why **three separate people** marked it "unclear." Perhaps take that information on-board? I mean, I'm pretty obviously keen to help people. That's why I've posted more than *fourteen thousand answers*.

Comment: I do not have code, my question is this:

I have a combo type select choosen, I need to change the color of 1 item in specific, ie as the image shows, I have 3 records, and I only have to change the background color, additionally I have more combos, so if I change the Class exchange all the combos of my html, then it would be by id of the combo.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with a simple line of CSS instead of using javascript ;-)

`.chosen-container .chosen-results li.active-result { color: red}`

Comment: The code must be javascript because it must be to a specific combo, I must modify a property from javascrip so that it does not affect the other combos.

Comment: What about adding a specific ID to differenciate the combos ?

Comment: I do not have code, my question is this:

I have a combo type select choosen, I need to change the color of 1 item in specific, ie as the image shows, I have 3 records, and I only have to change the background color, additionally I have more combos, so if I change the Class exchange all the combos of my html, then it would be by id of the combo.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("yourid").className += " MyClass";
```

Add below css

```
.MyClass{
    color: green
}
```